# Ansible command module can't execute arguments

Tags: ansible

an Ansible noobie here.

The issue i'm having is the when I used "command" module to execute a command, it will fail. Tried this on a remote host and localhost as well.

**BASIC INFO:**

Version: ansible 2.0.0 (devel 2c9d1257ba)

Core: (detached HEAD 5983d64d77) last updated 2015/05/30 07:22:33 (GMT +800)

Extras: (detached HEAD 1276420a3a) last updated 2015/05/30 07:22:41 (GMT +800)

**Ansible Host file**

```
local   ansible_ssh_host=127.0.0.1  ansible_ssh_port=22 ansible_ssh_user=root ansible_ssh_pass=a
```

**Command**

```
ansible -i ansible_hosts -m command -a "/usr/bin/ls" local
```

**Actual Result**

```
local | FAILED! => {u'msg': u'Traceback (most recent call last):\r\n 
File
"/root/.ansible/tmp/ansible-tmp-1436165888.5-23845581569171/command",
line 2139, in <module>\r\n    main()\r\n  File
"/root/.ansible/tmp/ansible-tmp-1436165888.5-23845581569171/command",
line 158, in main\r\n    module =
CommandModule(argument_spec=dict())\r\n  File
"/root/.ansible/tmp/ansible-tmp-1436165888.5-23845581569171/command",
line 606, in __init__\r\n    self._check_for_check_mode()\r\n  File
"/root/.ansible/tmp/ansible-tmp-1436165888.5-23845581569171/command",
line 1142, in _check_for_check_mode\r\n    for (k,v) in
self.params.iteritems():\r\nAttributeError: \'tuple\' object has no
attribute \'iteritems\'\r\n', u'failed': True, u'changed': False,
u'parsed': False, u'invocation': {u'module_name': u'command',
u'module_args': {u'_raw_params': u'/usr/bin/ls'}}}
```

Was there something wrong in my config?

Comment: User *Halberom* in IRC noted that the submodules were not pulled when performing git pull, thus causing a main repo-submodule repo out of sync.

by running 

    git submodule update --init --recursive

The issue was solve.

Comment: So this question is resolved?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question because the issue has apparently been resolved via updating a git submodule.

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like this question was resolved by running `git submodule update --init --recursive` in the checkout of Ansible that was being used.

If others run into the same problem, the easiest fix would be to install Ansible from the system package manager of the host from which it's being run, or `pip install Ansible` in a [virtualenv](http://iamzed.com/2009/05/07/a-primer-on-virtualenv/).